# How to fix net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in ajax GET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, https

I have a simple JS program that works with JQuery Ajax to ping a website and return the status code:

```
$.get("https://dev.tylernodes.com", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).done(function() {
               // TO DO ON DONE
            }).fail(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                 //This shows status code eg. 403
                 console.log("error", data.status);
                 //This shows status message eg. Forbidden
                 console.log("STATUS: "+xhr);
            }).always(function() {
                 //TO-DO after fail/done request.
                 console.log("ended");
            });
```

Whenever I use this though, I get an error: `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

I was wondering how would I fix this for the long term?

Comment: Why do you expect dev.tylernodes.com to resolve?

Comment: thats my website...

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist here: `Host dev.tylernodes.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`. Why do you expect it to exist for you?

Comment: Also, be aware that your use of PING here is a misnomer. You're making an HTTP Request. My understanding is that there is no way to do a true PING with JS/AJAX